# which build.gradle file Android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, gradle

I am following the instructions from Facebook on how to add Facebook sdk to my Android app but my Android studio has a bit different layout. Installed a brand new version of Android studio today and created a new project. I have two build.grade files under a folder called Gradle Scripts (this is default which studio creates for me). In the instructions it says to add some lines into the build.gradle file but I have two which is it? One has a light gray note which says Project the other says Module

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the build.gradle files should say (Module:app) next to it. That is where you will put the FaceBook dependencies.

In the Facebook instructions is say to add it to the Module-level file:

> Add this to Module-level /app/build.gradle before dependencies:

Also in the other Gradle file it will say:

> // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong in the individual module build.gradle files

Comment: My other one says Project:HelloWorldProject but the first line has a comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. Does this sound right?

Comment: You would not put it in that file.